# How are we able to Autowire the CrudRepository Interface even without creating a bean for it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface that extends the crud repository

```
package com.archie.repository.mysql;

import com.archie.model.dao.MysqlEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Integer> {

}
```

And without creating the bean of it I'm able to autowire it in the UserService Class as shown.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public void saveData(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(2);
        user.setUserAge(18);
        user.setUserName("Nish");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@Repository` annotation is not mandatory because Spring Boot autoconfigures the bean that extends `CrudRepository`.

**How is this happening?**

All repositories in Spring extend from:

```
@Indexed
public interface Repository<T, ID> {

}
```

The annotation `@Indexed` automatically creates the beans without defining any stereotype annotation like `@Repository`. Behind the scenes, Spring makes a metadata file generated at compile time to hold this info.

Further reading about [@Index annotation](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Indexed.html)